Is there any way to zip a folder so that it is just the zipped folder with the files inside, rather than it having another folder inside?
I am on windows, and am trying to use a fork of the dolphin emulator, which takes it's code from a zipped python312 folder. When I go into this folder, I get all the files inside immediately, without having to navigate into a subfolder named the same thing. However, when I zip a folder myself, it creates a folder inside the zipped folder, with the same name, that I then have to go into to access my files inside. Is there any way to make it so that it just zips the folder without creating another one inside it?
My files in the folder are at the directory: C:\Users\USER\Downloads\dolphin_modded_2\Python312.zip\Python312 (where the files are inside a folder in the .zip - I didn't add this folder, I just zipped a folder where they were directly in it)
The files in the dolphin version are in the directory:
C:\Users\USER\Downloads\dolphin_modded_2\dolphin\Binary\x64\python-embed\python312.zip (where the files are directly in the .zip)
They are in different locations because I was testing combining the files then zipping it in order to add things to it.
This is what the dolphin Folder looks like, and what the inside looks like.


This is what it looks like when I zip a folder, and what the inside looks like:

Inside the zipped folder: 
This is where my files are. 

Yes, there is a way to do this. You can select all the files in the folder you want to zip with ctrl + a, then right-click one of the files, and then navigate to compress to, then click on additional options ,then change the file type to be a zip. This should then create you a zipped folder with all the files you want without creating the subfolder. It will be named the same as whichever file you right-clicked on, with .zip at the end. You can change this to be python312 as per your example.
